# Swift Firebase chat room

Tags: swift, firebase, chat

I have chat app with possibility send messages one to one (fromId/toId). I want to upgrade it with chat rooms. How i can do that? What DB structure do i need for ChatingRoom? What else i need to do that?

My User.swift model:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class User: NSObject {

var id: String?
var name: String?
var login: String?
var email: String?
var profileImageUrl: String?
var role: String?
var isOnline: String?
init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.isOnline = dictionary["isOnline"] as? String
    self.id = dictionary["userID"] as? String
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    self.login = dictionary["username"] as? String
    self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    self.role = dictionary["role"] as? String
}
}
```

Message.swift model:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Message: NSObject {

var fromId: String?
var text: String?
var timestamp: NSNumber?
var toId: String?
var imageUrl: String?
var videoUrl: String?
var imageWidth: NSNumber?
var imageHeight: NSNumber?

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String
    self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String
    self.toId = dictionary["toId"] as? String
    self.timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? NSNumber
    self.imageUrl = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String
    self.videoUrl = dictionary["videoUrl"] as? String

    self.imageWidth = dictionary["imageWidth"] as? NSNumber
    self.imageHeight = dictionary["imageHeight"] as? NSNumber
}

func chatPartnerId() -> String? {
    return fromId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ? toId : fromId
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well currently you have From / To.

So To is going to be a room rather than a person.

Users will need to be able to join a room (or rooms) in order to see the messages that are sent to that room.

So your need a Rooms node.

If you have a messages node then you can just sort by To (room) instead of To (user) to get all the messages sent in that chat room. From will always be the User that wrote the message